# Área de circunferência

Tags: java, scanner

Boa noite! Estou começando em Java, e estou tentando completar a challenge de Área de Circunferência do URI.
Está dando um monte de problema:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)     at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)   at
>   Main.main(Main.java:9)

Este é o código.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        double raio = scan.nextDouble();
        double n = 3.14159;
        double area = Math.pow(raio,2) * n;

        System.out.println("A=" +area);

    }
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Copiei e colei teu código [aqui](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler) e rodou normal. Pode ser um problema no site de desafios... Também, pode ser que tu não tenhas preenchido a entrada...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()):

```
public double nextDouble()
Scans the next token of the input as a double. This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid double value. If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.
If the next token matches the Float regular expression defined above then the token is converted into a double value as if by removing all locale specific prefixes, group separators, and locale specific suffixes, then mapping non-ASCII digits into ASCII digits via Character.digit, prepending a negative sign (-) if the locale specific negative prefixes and suffixes were present, and passing the resulting string to Double.parseDouble. If the token matches the localized NaN or infinity strings, then either "Nan" or "Infinity" is passed to Double.parseDouble as appropriate.

Returns:
the double scanned from the input
Throws:
InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Float regular expression, or is out of range
NoSuchElementException - if the input is exhausted
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed
```

Ali diz que, para ser lançada uma `NoSuchElementException`, é porque a entrada "acabou". Provavelmente falta algo a ser preenchido como entrada.